# How to set a class on a view during runtime instead of interface builder

Tags: ios, swift, class, optimization, uiview

**Problem:**

I have the below class `myShadow` attached to a view `myView`.

The class is attached to the view as a custom class in interface builder.

However, there are times that I want to set the class while the app is running.

[image]

**Questions:**

> How can I instead programatically set the class `myShadow` to a view
>   `myView` at runtime, for example when the user taps a button `myButton`?
>   Is there a way to call the class as a regular function inside `ViewController`?

**Code:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!

    @IBAction func myButton(sender: AnyObject) {


        //// How to set `myShadow` class on `myView` here when tapping `myButton`? ////


    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}

class myShadow: UIView {

    var shadowLayer: CAShapeLayer!

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if shadowLayer == nil {
            shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 5).CGPath
            shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
            shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
            shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
            shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
            shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
            shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 5
            layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, atIndex: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift is a strongly typed language. This is a feature not a bug. Once you declare a variable it will be and remain that type. While swizzling and other tricks will work in a more dynamic language like objective-c, swift enforces type.

It would be better to either use an extension on `UIView` to add and remove the shadow layer. For example:

```
extension UIView
{
    func applyShadow()
    {
        let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 5).CGPath
        shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
        shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
        shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
        shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 5
        layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, atIndex: 0)
    }

    func removeShadow()
    {
        guard let sublayers = layer.sublayers where sublayers.count > 0 else { return }
        let shadowLayer = sublayers[0]
        if shadowLayer.shadowPath != nil
        {
            shadowLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
    }

}
```

Then you could say:

```
@IBAction func myButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let button = sender as? UIButton
    {
        button.applyShadow()  // if you want to apply it to the button 
        myView.applyShadow()  // if you want to apply it to some other view
    }
}
```

This works with any `UIView` or any subclass of `UIView`, but you're making assumptions about the structure of the view's layer hierarchy.

Or add a boolean property to `MyShadow` like `shouldShowShadow`

```
class MyShadow: UIView {

    var shadowLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    var shouldShowShadow = false

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if shadowLayer == nil && shouldShowShadow
        {
            shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 5).CGPath
            shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
            shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
            shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
            shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
            shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
            shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 5
            layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, atIndex: 0)
        }
        else if shadowLayer != nil && !shouldShowShadow
        {
            shadowLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
            shadowLayer = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Then say something like:

```
@IBAction func myButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.shadowView.shouldShowShadow = true
    self.shadowView.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

This only works on instances of `MyShadow`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible. If you need to create a class object programatically then you need to alloc init the object.

```
MyShadow *myShadow = [[MyShadow alloc] init];
```

Or else if the class you plan to modify has a specific inherited hierarchy you can type cast the specific object.

```
 MyShadow *myShadow = (MyShadow *)myShadow;
```

Or you can do some runtime swizzling using objc/runtime library, which is normally applicable to methods not to the class.

Suggestions for your case : Make "MyView" as a subclass of "MyShadow".

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go shortly.